# When is using whitespace for readability NOT allowed?

Tags: c, coding-style, whitespace

C seems to be pretty permissive when it comes to whitespace.

We can use or omit whitespace around an operator, between a function name and its parenthesized list of arguments, between an array name and its index, etc. in order to make code more readable. I understand this is a matter of preference.

The only place I can think of where whitespace is NOT allowed is this:

```
#include < stdio.h > // fatal error:  stdio.h : No such file or directory
```

What are the other contexts in C where whitespace cannot be used for readability?

Comment: The questions sounds as if all whitespace would make readability. This is by far not the case. `#include < stdio.h >` is not more readable than `#include <stdio.h>`. `int func ( int param )` is ugly as well.

Comment: `<stdio.h>` is basically a string with funny delimiters, letting the compiler know it's looking in a different set of search paths. Whitespace *is* allowed, but it's significant - `" stdio.h "` and `"stdio.h"` are not the same string, nor the same filename.

Comment: @glglgl I'm not implying that whitespace always makes code more readable. It can be used for that purpose, and I'm asking about contexts where that is not allowed. I can edit the question if it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, adding whitespace within a single token either makes the program invalid or changes the meaning of the token. An obvious example: `"foo"` and `" foo "` are both valid string literals with different values, because a string literal is a single token. Changing `123456` to `123 456` changes it from a single integer constant to two integer constants, resulting in a syntax error.

The exceptions to this involve the preprocessor.

You've already mentioned the `#include` directive. Note that given:

```
#include "header.h"
```

the `"header.h"` is not syntactically a string literal; it's processed before string literals are meaningful.  The syntax is similar, but for example a `\t` sequence in a header name isn't necessarily replaced by a tab character.

Newlines (which are a form of whitespace) are significant in preprocessor directives; you can't legally write:

```
#ifdef
    FOO
/* ... */
#endif
```

But whitespace other than newlines is permitted:

```
   # if SPACES_ARE_ALLOWED_HERE
#endif
```

And there's one case I can think of where whitespace is permitted *between preprocessor tokens* but it changes the meaning. In the definition of a function-like macro, the `(` that introduces the parameter list must immediately follow the macro name. This:

```
#define TWICE(x) ((x) + (x))
```

defines `TWICE` as a function-like macro that takes one argument. But this:

```
#define NOT_TWICE (x) ((x) + (x))
```

defines `NOT_TWICE` as an ordinary macro with no arguments that expands to `(x) ((x) + (x))`.

This rule applies only to macro *definitions*; a macro invocation follows the normal rules, so you can write either `TWICE(42)` or `TWICE ( 42 )`.

Answer (score 2):

White spaces are not allowed for readability (are significant) within a lexical token. I.e. within an identifier (`foo bar` is different from `foobar`), within a number (`123 456` is different from `123456`), within a string (that's your example basically) or within an operator (`+ +` is different from `++` and `+ =` is different from `+=`). Between those you can add as much white space as you want, but when you add white space inside such a token you will break the lexical token into two separate tokens (or change the value in case of string constants), thus changing the meaning of your code .

In most cases the code with the added white space is either equivalent to the original code or results in a syntax error. But there are exceptions. For example:

```
return a +++ b;
```

is the same as

```
return a ++ + b;
```

but is different from:

```
return a + ++ b;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall you need to be very careful with function-like macros, as in such dummy example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum(x, y) ((x)+(y))

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", sum(2, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

the:

```
#define sum(x, y) ((x)+(y))
```

is different thing than say:

```
#define sum (x, y) ((x)+(y))
```

The latter one is object-like macro, that replaces exactly with `(x, y) ((x)+(y))`, that is parameters are not being subsituted (as it happens in function-like macro).